# Angular 6+ binding [src] in ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

Tags: angular, string-interpolation, pdf-viewer, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

I'm using **ngx-extended-pdf-viewer** ( [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer) ) to render a PDF and it works when i set directly the path+fileName, as below:

```
 <ngx-extended-pdf-viewer [src]="'assets/example.pdf'" 
            [showPrintButton]="false" [showBookmarkButton]="false"
            [showOpenFileButton]="false" 
            [showSidebarOnLoad]="false"
            [showSidebarButton]="true" 
            delayFirstView="6000" useBrowserLocale="false">
          </ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>
```

I'd like to create a variable in .TS and binding it in [src] like below:

**Typescript**

```
...
ngOnInit() {
    this.filePathAndName = "'assets/example.pdf'";
...
```

**HTML**

```
 <ngx-extended-pdf-viewer [src]="{{filePathAndName}}" 
            [showPrintButton]="false" [showBookmarkButton]="false"
            [showOpenFileButton]="false" 
            [showSidebarOnLoad]="false"
            [showSidebarButton]="true" 
            delayFirstView="6000" useBrowserLocale="false">
          </ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>
```

But It doesn't work.

The major problem is the [**src**] needs to have the two symbols:
Quotation marks ( " ) following by Apostrophe ( ' )  ...  " ' path+name ' " (without the spaces)

**My question is : How can I put a valid value in a variable in Typescript to render properly in HTML in this specific scenario ?**

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't need those quotation marks. Those are only for literal string bindings. Try this:

```
this.filePathAndName = "assets/example.pdf";

<ngx-extended-pdf-viewer *ngIf="filePathAndName" [src]="filePathAndName"
```

Answer (score 0):

May be am late to reply, will be helpful for someone in future.

**HTML code :**

```
  <ngx-extended-pdf-viewer *ngIf="currentPdf"
    [src]="currentPdf" useBrowserLocale="false"
    style="height: 100%; width: 100%"
    [delayFirstView]="1000"
    [showHandToolButton]="true"
    [handTool] = false>
  </ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>
```

**Typescript code:**

```
public currentPdf: string

displayPdf() {

    // setTimeout(() => {
      this.service.getPdfExtractedContent(this.id)
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            this.currentPdf = URL.createObjectURL(this.b64toBlob(data.ExtractedByte,'data:application/pdf;base64', 1024));

          },
          error => {
            console.log(error);
          }
        );
    // }, 500);

  }


  b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
    const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
    const byteArrays = [];

    for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
      const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

      const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
      for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
      }

      const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
      byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }

    const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
    return blob;
  }
```

Comment: I believe you have to explain your solution. It looks like a working solution, but it has little to do with the original question. Let me guess: your PDF file is a BLOB provided by a service? More specifially, by `this.service.getPdfExtractedContent(this.id)`?

Comment: @StephanRauh, yes PDF file is a BLOB provided by a service this.service.getPdfExtractedContent(this.id) .

Comment: I've got good news for you. When I started implementing the PDF viewer, my team used your idea to display the Blob. Since version 0.9.21, the `src` also accepts Blobs, Uint8Arrays, and ArrayBuffers. If you've got a base64-encoded string, you can use the attribute `base64Src`.